# How to groupby for one column and then sort_values for another column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
  SampleID      expr             Gene  Period                     tag
4   HSB103  7.214731  ENSG00000198615       5  HSB103|ENSG00000198615
2   HSB103  4.214731  ENSG00000198725       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198725
5   HSB100  3.214731  ENSG00000198615       4  HSB100|ENSG00000198615
1   HSB106  2.200031  ENSG00000198780       5  HSB106|ENSG00000198780
0   HSB103  1.214731  ENSG00000198780       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198780
3   HSB103  0.214731  ENSG00000198615       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198615
```

What I want to do is group by the `Gene` and then sort by descending `expr`, so that it looks like:

```
  SampleID      expr             Gene  Period                     tag
0   HSB103  7.214731  ENSG00000198615       5  HSB103|ENSG00000198615
1   HSB100  3.214731  ENSG00000198615       4  HSB100|ENSG00000198615
2   HSB103  0.214731  ENSG00000198615       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198615
3   HSB103  4.214731  ENSG00000198725       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198725
4   HSB106  2.200031  ENSG00000198780       5  HSB106|ENSG00000198780
5   HSB103  1.214731  ENSG00000198780       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198780
```

I've tried the following, but none of them work:

**Attempt 1:**

```
p4p5.sort_values(by=['expr'], ascending=[False], inplace=True).groupby(['Gene'])
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
p4p5.groupby(['Gene'])
p4p5.sort_values(by=['expr'], ascending=[False], inplace=True)
```

**Update to question**:

Once I group and sort, how can I then filter the dataframe to keep only the bottom 10% of expression per gene group? When I say `bottom 10%`, I mean in the theoretical distribution sense, NOT if I had 100 rows per gene, I'd get 10 rows after filtering. I imagine it would it be something like:

```
p4p5.sort_values(by=['Gene','expr'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True).quantile([0.1])
```

Comment: for your updated question, what do you mean by filter? do you want to remove the bottom 10% of your dataframe or keep only these 10%?

Comment: I want to keep only the bottom 10%

Comment: what do you mean by 'theoritical distribution'? not sure to understand

Comment: I mean I want the actual expression values to be taken into account when determining the bottom 10%, not just choosing the bottom 10 rows per gene. For instance, in R, the command would be something like this:
`group_by(Gene) %>% arrange(Gene, desc(expr)) %>% filter(expr < quantile(expr, 0.1))`

Answer (score 4):

you don't need `groupby` here, just `sort_values` by both columns such as:

```
p4p5.sort_values(by=['Gene','expr'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)
```

EDIT: for updated question, you can use `groupby` and `tail` such as:

```
p4p5_bottom10 = (p4p5.sort_values(by='expr', ascending=False).groupby('Gene')
                     .apply(lambda df_g: df_g.tail(int(len(df_g)*0.1))))
```

you can add `.reset_index(drop=True)` at the end too

2nd EDIT: hope this time I understood well, you can do it like this:

```
#first sort 
p4p5= p4p5.sort_values(['Gene','expr'], ascending=[True,False]).reset_index(drop=True)
# select the part of the data under quantile 10% (reset_index not mandatory)
p4p5_bottom10  = (p4p5[p4p5.groupby('Gene')['expr'].apply(lambda x: x < x.quantile(0.1))]
                       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! When I try that and print p4p5_bottom10, I get:  

`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [SampleID, expr, Gene, Period, tag]
Index: []`

Comment: @claudiadast it depends on how many rows you have in each group. If you have less than 10 rows per gene, then getting the bottom 10% of each gene result to no data selected as `int(len(df_g)*0.1)` is zero if `len(df_g)<10`

Comment: @claudiadast see my 2nd EDIT, if it is not what you want I really don't get it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Gene','expr'],ascending=[True,False]).groupby('Gene').tail(3)
  SampleID      expr             Gene  Period                     tag
0   HSB103  7.214731  ENSG00000198615       5  HSB103|ENSG00000198615
2   HSB100  3.214731  ENSG00000198615       4  HSB100|ENSG00000198615
5   HSB103  1.214731  ENSG00000198615       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198615
1   HSB103  4.214731  ENSG00000198725       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198725
3   HSB106  2.200031  ENSG00000198780       5  HSB106|ENSG00000198780
4   HSB103  1.214731  ENSG00000198780       4  HSB103|ENSG00000198780
```

Comment: The problem with `tail` directly after the `groupby` is that to get bottom 10% of each gene (how I understood the question), you need to be sure that all the groups are the same size as `tail` only accepts an integer and not percentage (or at least not to my knowledge)

Comment: @Ben.T, looks like the initial post that i understood, but yes in the sense you are right, so your answer would meet that.

Comment: the question has been edited, we are both wrong apparently  ^^

Comment: yes Ben :) , it will happen because its been 50 mins since then ques edited many times so definitely ans will differ.